# Lock and transaction in postgres that should block a query

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking, mvcc

Let's assume in SQL window 1 I do:

```
-- query 1 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE post SET title = 'edited' WHERE id = 1;
-- note that there is no explicit commit
```

Then from another window (window 2) I do:

```
-- query 2
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = 1;
```

I get:

```
1 | original title
```

Which is fine as the default isolation level is READ COMMITTED and because query 1 is never committed, the change it performs is not readable until I explicitly commit from window 1.

In fact if I, in window 1, do:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I can then see the change if I re-run query 2.

```
1 | edited
```

My question is:

Why is query 2 returning fine the first time I run it? I was expecting it to block as the transaction in window 1 was not committed yet and the lock placed on row with `id = 1` was (should be) an unreleased exclusive one that should block a read like the one performed in window 2. All the rest makes sense to me but I was expecting the `SELECT` to get stuck until an explicit commit in window 1 was executed.

Comment: PostgreSQL uses MVCC (multiversion concurrency control) rather than locks. You get older values rather than blocking. As you can see, this greatly improves concurrency but can be somewhat harder to wrap your head around.

Comment: @DanielLyons: To say "rather than locks" would be going to far ... There is locking alright, writing just does not usually block reading and vice-versa.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think you're letting your depth of knowledge (which is vast) to unnecessarily color a straight-forward question based on a common misapprehension. The kind of locking the OP is expecting to be there just isn't, thanks to MVCC. It's true that some operations lock and undoubtedly some of the internals use locks, nothing in the question should cause the expected locking  behavior.

Comment: @DanielLyons: It's the difference between locking and blocking. The "special" ingredient here are non-blocking locks.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you describe is normal and expected in any transactional relational database.

If PostgreSQL showed you the value `edited` for the first `SELECT` it'd be wrong to do so - that's called a "dirty read", and is bad news in databases.

PostgreSQL would be allowed to wait at the `SELECT` until you committed or rolled back, but it isn't required to by the SQL standard, you haven't told it you want to wait, and it doesn't have to wait for any technical reason, so it returns the data you asked for immediately. After all, until it's committed, that `update` only kind-of exists - it still might or might not happen.

If PostgreSQL always waited here, then you'd quickly land up with a situation where only one connection could be doing anything with the database at a time. Not pretty for performance, and totally unnecessary the vast majority of the time.

If you want to wait for a concurrent `UPDATE` (or `DELETE`), you'd use `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`. (But be aware that this won't work for `INSERT`).

---

Details:

`SELECT` without a `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE` clause does not take any row level locks. So it sees whatever is the current committed row, and is not affected by any in-flight transactions that might be modifying that row. The concepts are explained in the [MVCC section of the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html). The general idea is that PostgreSQL is copy-on-write, with versioning that allows it to return the correct copy based on what the transaction or statement could "see" at the time it started - what PostgreSQL calls a "snapshot".

In the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation snapshots are taken at the statement level, so if you `SELECT` a row, `COMMIT` a change to it from another transaction, and `SELECT` it again you'll see different values even within one transation. You can use `SNAPSHOT` isolation if you don't want to see changes committed after the transaction begins, or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation to add further protection against certain kinds of transaction inter-dependencies.

See [the transaction isolation chapter in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

If you want a `SELECT` to wait for in-progress transactions to commit or rollback changes to rows being selected, you must use `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`. This will block on the lock taken by an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` until the transaction that took the lock rolls back or commits.

`INSERT` is different, though - the tuples just don't exist to other transactions until commit. The only way to wait for concurrent `INSERT`s is to take an `EXCLUSIVE` table-level lock, so you know nobody else is changing the table while you read it. Usually the need to do that means you have a design problem in the application though - your app should not *care* if there are uncommitted `insert`s still in flight.

See [the explicit locking chapter of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

Answer (score 2):

In [PostgreSQL's MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) implementation, the principle is reading does not block writing and vice-versa. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html)

> The main advantage of using the MVCC model of concurrency control
> rather than locking is that in MVCC locks acquired for querying
> (reading) data do not conflict with locks acquired for writing data,
> and so reading never blocks writing and writing never blocks reading.
> PostgreSQL maintains this guarantee even when providing the strictest
> level of transaction isolation through the use of an innovative
> *Serializable Snapshot Isolation* (SSI) level.

Each transaction only sees (mostly) what has been committed before the transaction began.

That does *not* mean there'd be no locking. Not at all. For many operations various kinds of locks are acquired. And various strategies are applied to resolve possible conflicts.